# AWS Glue - version control and setting up for continuous integration

Tags: github, aws-glue, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, aws-codecommit

We are in the process of setting up the CI / CD process for AWS Glue ETL Process. The existing ETL process contains the following AWS Glue Components - Crawlers, Registered tables in catalog, Jobs, Triggers and workflows.

Obviously the first step is to set up a code repository and link the existing artifacts from different components mentioned above to the repository, which will ideally need to facilitate the developers in performing the check-ins and pull request from the tool (Something similar to ADF and Databricks). However as far as we have explored, AWS glue does not have integration to any of the source code repository which can directly provide this feature unless we are missing something.

Hence what is the method to setup the environment for CI (I'm still not talking about CD), the below link gives a reference for CI/CD:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/implement-continuous-integration-and-delivery-of-serverless-aws-glue-etl-applications-using-aws-developer-tools/

However it mentions at the beginning that, *AWS CloudFormation template file for deploying the ETL jobs are both committed to version control* - so not clear on how this is done for the on-going regular commits from the developers.

Answer (score 0):

> However as far as we have explored, AWS glue does not have integration
> to any of the source code repository which can directly provide this
> feature unless we are missing something.

Correct, Glue does not have VC integration.

I develop (python and cloudformation) locally on vscode and use it's git integration plugin.  And I use a [container](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-glue-libs#!) if I want to test something locally, but Glue also has a Dev Endpoint for similar tasks.

Comment: Are there any reference links available for a similar kind of implementation, specifically on the steps that needs to be performed for this integration. While we are still exploring, the core considerations as mentioned above are, the existing process contains various components (Crawlers, AWS Glue Jobs, Triggers and AWS Glue workflows) and we are looking at source code integration for this entire ecosystem.

Comment: Like Best Practices docs?  I wish there were, but I haven't come across them